# Terms filter not matching with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

My document's mapping:

```
 ...
 "user.id": {
   "type": "string",
   "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
  ...
```

An example document that is indexed:

```
{ "user": { "id": "123" } }
```

With the following query:

```
"query" : {
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : { }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "terms" : {
        "user.id" : [ "123, foo" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get no hits.

Whilst a term filter with just "123" matches successfully.

From what I've read in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) the terms filter should match "any" of the provided values. So in my case the fact that "foo" doesn't match to the `userId` then the document should match since "123" does match.

Have I misunderstood the terms filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting `"123, foo"` as a single string. There is no document in your collection with that user id. If you submit "123" and "foo" as separate strings, i.e. `"user.id" : [ "123", "foo" ]`, your example document should match the query.

Comment: In the query I'm submitting them as separate strings in an array, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Thats what I'm already doing, see my question. It doesn't match.

Comment: If the code in the question is correct, that's not what you're doing. Your array `"user.id"` contains just one string: `"123, foo"`. If you want to submit these words as separate strings, you need quotes around both of them: `[ "123", "foo" ]`

Comment: Thanks for the keen eye, appreciate it.